# Android Studio warns memory leak on context which injected with hilt @ApplicationContext

Tags: android, android-studio, dagger-hilt

I use Hilt for DI and recently (after some update) android studio warns me on context filed annotated with `@ApplicationContext` for memory leaks. as far as I know I know application context will available while app is running and it shouldn't cause memory leak but it seems lint think differently. am I wrong or it's just a bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this by removing `val` and use context as WeakRefrence

```
class ActivityViewModel @ViewModelInject constructor(
            @ApplicationContext context: ApplicationContext,
){
    private val context: WeakReference<Context> = WeakReference(context)

}
```